# Changing startup project in Visual Studio 2017 with github integration

Tags: github, visual-studio-2017

Without gitub and git integration, one can just right click a solution, go to Properties and select the startup project.  With a github repository project I do not see how to do that.  How can you change the startup project with a project in github source control?

Comment: Perhaps related, though hard to tell: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7304625/1531971

Comment: Thanks!  It wasn't totally applicable, but it helped me find the context menu "Select Startup Item" below the main menu.  The dropdown shows all csproj items that you can select.