# Visual Studio 2019 Debugger "Unable to start program ... Access is denied" caused by build file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, vst

I'm running Visual Studio 2019 on Windows and having an issue running the debugger.
When I try to run the Local Windows Debugger, I the following Error:

```
Unable to start program
'C:\Users\userName\OneDrive\Documents\...\ALL_BUILD'.

Access is denied
```

This ALL_BUILD file is a build file for a specific SDK that I'm using (Steinberg VST SDK). I tried running VS2019 as administrator but still get the error. Anybody have any suggestions on how to solve or investigate this issue?

Comment: This is a built-in CMake target, you cannot Debug it. You probably want to Debug *your* program. You need to set *your* program as the Startup Project, instead of the ALL_BUILD project. See these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013309/visual-studio-debugger-error-unable-to-start-program-specified-file-cannot-be-f/7013665).

Comment: See also this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37994396/5251059 on how to set the `VS_STARTUP_PROJECT` property in your CMakeLists.txt file.